# Unpack jars using maven

Tags: maven

I am trying to unpack a specific jar to a specific folder in my project.
I am using maven-dependency-plugin to do that.
Because I've changed it to unpack-dependencies, so while I'm at it, I'd like to find the answer to the following question. What is the difference between 'unpack' and 'unpack-dependencies'?
Edit: I've got one answer, but the major answer is still missing. I'll calirify that in any way I am unable to get the jar to unpack.

```
 <execution>
                    <id>copy-jars-to-lib-dir</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>extrct-oms-core-artifacts</id>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>group1</groupId> 
                                <artifactId>atrifactId</artifactId>
                                <version>9.3.0.0699.1-oms</version>
                                <outputDirectory>myOutPut</outputDirectory>                                 
                                <excludes>...</excludes>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [`maven-dependency-plugin` documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/plugin-info.html) for the difference between `unpack` and `unpack-dependencies` goals.

Put simply,

- [`unpack`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html) goal should be used to unpack a jar that is not a dependency of your project. You configure it with the `artifactItems` parameter.
- [`unpack-dependencies`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-dependencies-mojo.html) goal should be used to unpack all jar dependencies of your project.

Comment: Well it appears I had a version problem regarding the other question. Rookie me. Thank you.